# Matrix Exponential [Multiplication - C Code]

Tags: c, matrix

I'm currently developing a function to calculate the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential). For that, I need a function that multiplies a X matrix n times. The code below gives good results for small values of n, but when increasing this parameter, the code produces wrong outputs, probably due to the large numbers generated. Is there any solution to this, or another way to compute the matrix multiplication?

EDIT:

- The Matrix M is statically allocated.

Code:

```
void Multiply_Matrix_N_Times( double M[NL][NC], int L, int N )
{
double A[NL][NC];
double A_AUX[NL][NC];

int i, j;

for(i=0;i<L;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<L;j++)
    {
        if(i==j)
            A[i][j]=1;
        else
            A[i][j]=0;
    }
}

for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
{
    Multiply_Matrices(A,M,A_AUX,L,L,L,L);
    Copy_Matrix(A_AUX,A,L,L);
}

//printMatrix_REAL(A,L,L);
//getchar();

Copy_Matrix(A,M,L,L);
}
```

Comment: Do you statically allocate M? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: Yes. It is statically allocated. @atru

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Maybe you are better of if you perform diagonalization A=MDM^T, as exp(A)=Mexp(D)M^T and for D=diag(x1, ..., xn), exp(D)=diag(exp(x1),...,exp(xn)).

Comment: Perhaps you're allocation is too small? I mean M[V1][V2] where either or both V1 and V2 become smaller than what you're requesting? Trivial, but it happens.

Comment: The allocation is enough. The problem is the overflow.

Comment: @Jodocus What is the x1,x2,...,xn in the D diagonal?

Comment: @EmanuelCamacho The eigenvalues, provided A is diagonalizable. If not, you have to determine Jordan normal form; the matrix exponential however has a similiar structure.

Comment: Please show an example of input, desired output, and actual output. "produces wrong outputs" is not a valid problem description.

Comment: Too much code missing from this post.

Comment: Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is the first value of `N` for which the code fails? What are the array dimensions? What are the initial array values? What results do you expect? What results do you get?

Comment: I discovered the problem. To calculate the matrix exponential I'm using a factorial function. The factorial returns, for some values of N, infinity.